# What is the name of this tonal marking system?

Tags: tones, notation

What is the name of this tonal marking system?

> [image: pic]

**please do not try to explain the picture** - the picture is clear enough itself.

Comment: "古四声" or simply "汉语声调"

Comment: https://wapbaike.baidu.com/item/四声

Comment: What is the name of book you got this picture from?  I saw something similar in some books of 19th century.

Comment: @OmniBus the book is 《四川泸州方言研究》but many other old articles, papers, studies and books (at least dealing with Southwestern Mandarin) like to use these notations as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **发圈法**.

《内江市志 方言》：

> [image]

here it says:

> 标调用传统的四角发圈法

so we have **(四角)发圈法**

[百度百科：发圈法](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=KJBksxr98o3lESVeJvhro_PYu1LWiECw6bGWY2wwQIxGsr7Qf0OOGzsR_7y-nlfIJ3QeiUtxWAz4JgaxkddNfjPQqkuyNrSTOQPxBWFoIAr1duvfgpcmbMExroptJs1e)

> **发圈法**
>
> 发圈法，是指一种标记声调的方法。
>
> 能够独立区别意义的调值的类别称为调类。调类可以从共时角度编号并命名，也可以参考历时因素命名。
>
> 汉语方言的调类系统大多与中古汉语的平、上、去、入四声系统和声母的清浊系统有对应关系，通常根据这种历时对应关系来定调名：与平上去入四声对应的调类，今调名仍称平上去入；与中古清声母对应的调类今称阴调，与中古浊声母对应的调类今称阳调。

and

[百度互动百科](http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%8F%91%E5%9C%88%E6%B3%95) says:

> 标记声调的一种方法。
>
> 能够独立区别意义的调值的类别称为调类。调类可以从共时角度编号并命名，也可以参考历时因素命名。汉语方言的调类系统大多与中古汉语的平、上、去、入四声系统和声母的清浊系统有对应关系，通常根据这种历时对应关系来定调名：与平上去入四声对应的调类，今调名仍称平上去入；与中古清声母对应的调类今称阴调，与中古浊声母对应的调类今称阳调。
>
> 用这种命名法命名的调类系统可以用发圈法标记，中国传统语音学是用附加在汉字的四角的四个半圆来表示；如果因古声母清浊影响而产生了声调分化，则在因受古浊声母影响而形成的调类号下加短横，这样，四个声调就变成八个。具体方法是：在音节或汉字的四角用带缺口的小圈标记，从左下角开始，按顺时针方向依次为阴平、阴上、阴去、阴入，相应的阳调则在小圈下加短横线表示。例如：
>
> 阴平: 【半圆在左下】（诗 阴上: 【半圆在左上】（使 阴去: 试）【半圆在右上】 阴入: 识）【半圆在右下】